# How to invite user using Api in mail chimp

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

```
 I am integrating mail chimp API in my rails project 
 I am using OAUTH2 API Documentation and following the below ref.
```

> http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/how-to-use-oauth2/

```
 It integrate successfully and return an access token.

 My Project has a requirement that Admin can invite user 
 and give the permission of each user using Api same like below image.
```

[image]

```
 Is there Any endpoint available in a API that accept the parameters 
 like access token,user_email and user_type and add/update the visitor same like web ?
```

Answer (score 0):

there was in the MailChimp 2.0. It has been removed in the 3.0 (I don't know why). I'm trying to make the same call as the site is when you invite a user but the API has an integrated Chapcha / antiforgery as you can see in the picture.

```
 Request URL:https://us16.admin.mailchimp.com/account/users/invite-post
 Request Method:POST

 --BODY
 email:[EMAIL]
 role:author
 welcome_msg:[Message] (Optional)
 g-recaptcha-response:[CAPTCH]
 __csrf_token:[TOKEN]
```

[image]